# Convert all values in one column to string that correspond to another value in another column

Tags: r, list, type-conversion, bioinformatics

I have a [dataframe with all of the GeneIDs that correspond to each KEGG Pathway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSlMd.png). I want to convert the GeneIDs into a semi-colon separated string for each KEGG Pathway, such that I have a dataframe that has two columns, with the first column being all of the unique KEGG PathwayIDs and the other, contains strings of GeneIds corresponding to each PathwayID.

(for the first value, first column) path:mmu00010 and (for the first value, second column) "103988;106557;110695;11522 ...." etc

Answer (score 1):

You may use `aggregate` to group the pathway IDs by gene ID. Thereafter use `paste` in an `apply` to `collapse` the strings and separate them by a semicolon.

```
dat2 <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(path.id ~ gene.id, dat, gsub, pattern="\\D",
          replacement=""))
dat2 <- transform(dat2,
                 string=apply(da2t[-1], 1, paste, collapse=";"))[-(2:4)]
dat2
#   gene.id            string
# 1      10 00010;00020;00030
# 2      11 00010;00020;00030
# 3      12 00010;00020;00030
# 4      13 00010;00020;00030
# 5      14 00010;00020;00030
# 6      15 00010;00020;00030
```

You also could do this in one step if you don't mind it's getting a little `do.call`y.

```
dat3 <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(path.id ~ gene.id, dat, function(x) 
  do.call(paste, c(as.list(gsub("\\D", "", x)), sep = ";"))))
dat3
#   gene.id           path.id
# 1      10 00010;00020;00030
# 2      11 00010;00020;00030
# 3      12 00010;00020;00030
# 4      13 00010;00020;00030
# 5      14 00010;00020;00030
# 6      15 00010;00020;00030
```

---

*Toy data*

```
dat <- structure(list(gene.id = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), path.id = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("path:mmu00010", "path:mmu00020", "path:mmu00030"
), class = "factor")), out.attrs = list(dim = c(gene.id = 6L, 
path.id = 3L), dimnames = list(gene.id = c("gene.id=10", "gene.id=11", 
"gene.id=12", "gene.id=13", "gene.id=14", "gene.id=15"), path.id = c("path.id=path:mmu00010", 
"path.id=path:mmu00020", "path.id=path:mmu00030"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

head(dat)
#   gene.id       path.id
# 1      10 path:mmu00010
# 2      11 path:mmu00010
# 3      12 path:mmu00010
# 4      13 path:mmu00010
# 5      14 path:mmu00010
# 6      15 path:mmu00010
```